# What is wrong with this syntax for creating a temp table in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to create a temp table in Bigquery and I keep hitting errors. I'm on the front end of learning SQL and I'm sure I am missing a difference in syntax. Any help on where I'm getting this wrong would be appreciated!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
  continent nvarchar(255),
  location nvarchar(255),
  date datetime,
  population numeric,
  new_vaccinations numeric,
  current_population_vaccinated numeric
)
INSERT INTO #PercentPopulationVaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date,dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER(PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS current_population_vaccinated
FROM `covid-data-project-368212.covid.coviddeaths` dea
JOIN `covid-data-project-368212.covid.covidvaccinations` vac
  ON dea.location = vac.location
  AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent is not null  
ORDER BY 2,3
SELECT *, (current_population_vaccinated/population)*100
FROM #PercentPopulationVaccinated
;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual error message you are getting. However, I suspect the issue is that you’ve missed the semi-colon after each statement

Answer (score 0):

`#` starts a comment. Please do not use this character in a table name. There were missing `;` and the key word `temp`. Please only use supported data types of BigQuery. The tables of your sample cannot be accessed in public.

```sql
CREATE temp TABLE PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
  continent string,
  location string,
  date datetime,
  population numeric,
  new_vaccinations numeric,
  current_population_vaccinated numeric
);
INSERT INTO PercentPopulationVaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date,dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER(PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS current_population_vaccinated
FROM `covid-data-project-368212.covid.coviddeaths` dea
JOIN `covid-data-project-368212.covid.covidvaccinations` vac
  ON dea.location = vac.location
  AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent is not null  
ORDER BY 2,3;
SELECT *, (current_population_vaccinated/population)*100
FROM PercentPopulationVaccinated
;
```